# Make a get request after the first one is finished Getx

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

i want make get request after the first one finished because i need to send data from the **response of first request** with the **body of second request** to the server .. how i do this with getx

thanks

```js
class ProductsController extends GetxController with StateMixin<Posts> {

  @override
  void onInit() {
    getData();
    super.onInit();
  }

  getData() async {
    try {
      change(null, status: RxStatus.loading());
      await postsApiProvider
          .getPosts()
          .then((value) {
      
        change(value, status: RxStatus.success());
      });
    } catch (exception) {
      change(null, status: RxStatus.error(exception.toString()));
    }
  }

  // i want this function fire after getData() 
  _getRelated() async {
    try {
      await postsApiProvider
          .getRelated(
            price: value.region  ----> because i need access to getDate values 
           )
          .then((value) {
      
      });
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

I tried that method but it didn't work :

```js
  @override
  void onReady() {
    _getRelated();
    super.onReady();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your result by using `finally`. But I would suggest creating a function for that, so that in future if you want to add one more function based on second function's callback then you can easily achieve it.

Here's the example:

```
gloablfun()async{
 await getData();
 await _getRelated();
}
```

then you can call the global function in the `onInit` method:

```js
 @override
  void onInit() {
    gloablfun();
    super.onInit();
  }
```

By using this way, you can add more functions in the future and your code will look cleaner than before.

Answer (score 0):

try using try with finally e.g

```
 //a sample model which is have data
 final Rx<MyModel> model = Model().obs;
 @override
  void onInit() {
   myFunctiontocall();
    super.onInit();
  }
 
 myFunctiontocall() async{

   try{
    // from the first function
    // make a function that will have data to the model
    myFirstFunctionToRun();
   }finally{
    // from done process in the above next is the finally
    // which next to be run
    // call the second function but make sure the model
    // have data
    thenFinallymySecondFunctiontoRun();
   }

  }
```